# What is this telling me and How do I fix it

Tags: libraries, shared-library

error while loading shared libraries: libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: What are your Ubuntu version and its CPU architecture?

Answer (score 0):

This means that this library file was not found.

For 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS you have to install this library from the [*libwebkitgtk-1.0-0* package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0):

```
sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
```